# Converting array elements to hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array with the following elements:

```
results = ["test=complete", "test2=passed", "test3=failed", "test4=successful"]
```

I want to convert this array into a hash with the following keys and values:

```
results_hash = {"test": "complete", "test2": "passed", "test3": "failed", "test4": "successful"}
```

How can I do this? Not sure if best to use set, hash, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
results = ["test=complete", "test2=passed", "test3=failed", "test4=successful"]
results_hash = results.map{|str| str.split("=") }.to_h
# => {"test"=>"complete", "test2"=>"passed", "test3"=>"failed", "test4"=>"successful"}
```

Edit: As @sawa comments, the keys should be symbols. This is a way:

```
results.map{|str| a,b = str.split("="); [a.to_sym, b] }.to_h
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants.

Comment: How ? `undefined method 'to_h' for #<Array:0xba4e858>`

Comment: @ray The OP wanted symbol keys, but this answer gives string keys.

Comment: @sawa Yes, I saw it later, but still not getting -  to_h is method for Array object ?

Comment: @ray If you really get undefined method error for `Array#to_h`, then your Ruby configuration must be some non-standard one. `Array#to_h` has been in plain Ruby for a long time.

Comment: @sawa Thank you,  I will check my configuration.

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby 2.6:

```
results.to_h{|s| s.split("=").then{|k, v| [k.to_sym, v]}}
# => {:test=>"complete", :test2=>"passed", :test3=>"failed", :test4=>"successful"}
```

Comment: Good to know. I see `Kernel#then` will be an alias of `Kernel#yield_self` (documented at [Object#yield_self\(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-yield_self).

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is also new, but my focus in pointing to 2.6 was the fact that `Hash#to_h` can now take a block.

Comment: Hi, how can I get RuBy 2.6? Its not given in ruby site yet.

Comment: @Rajagopalan You cannot get Ruby 2.6 yet, but you can get Ruby 2.6-preview3 at https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2018/11/06/ruby-2-6-0-preview3-released/, whose features won't be different from Ruby 2.6; only bug fixes may be done.

Comment: Oh okay, that I am aware of it. Can you please let me know you are seeing the so file? because I heard that in Ruby 2.6 it includes JIT compiler?

Comment: Thanks, it was something new to me

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
array = ['test=passed', 'test=failed']

num_of_elements = array.length 



x = array[0].split("")

y = array[1].split("")

array = x + y

x.delete_if {|x| x.match('=')}
y.delete_if {|x| x.match('=')}

test_arr = x[0..3].join()
fail = x[4..9].join()

test_arr_2 = y[0..3].join()

fail_2 = y[4..9].join()

results = {}

results.compare_by_identity

results["#{test_arr}"] = fail
results["#{test_arr_2}"] = fail_2


puts results
```